# FDOGraphicsLayer IGraphicsContainer Reset/Next throw 'not implemented'

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3

Running ArcGIS 9.3.2 w/ ArcFM.

```c#
protected override void InternalClick()
{
    var d = _App.Document as IMxDocument;
    var m = d.FocusMap;
    var c = m as IGraphicsContainer;

    c.Reset();
    for( var e = c.Next(); e != null; e = c.Next() ) {
        var p = e as IElementProperties3;
    }
}
```

If the Active Annotation Target is set to anything other than '<Default>' then c.Reset() and c.Next() throw 'not implemented' exceptions.  I interpret this as FDOGraphicsLayer not implementing those methods.  Is this expected ?  I could not find any documentation that mentions this, nor does it seem correct.

I currently work around the issue by calling c.LocateElementsByEnvelope and pass it the ActiveView extents (basically locate all elements).  Casting m to IGraphicsContainerSelect and calling SelectAllElements also works.  Both seem like hacks.

Comment: Do you mean ArcGIS 9.3.1 SP2?  This is a pretty arcane coding issue for GSE.  Esri forums might be more appropriate, but 9.x releases are now all Retired.

Comment: Perhaps, but the new ESRI forums don't seem to get the same arcobjects traffic as here, maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.  My hope is that enough people have stored their graphics in the database, instead of the map doc, that someone must surely have come across this before.